# TextView text cutting off in column of TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

There are three columns in `TableLayout`, First and Second Column contains `TextView` with text and other properties, and third one contains `TextView` just for spacing.

But there is problem with first column `TextView`'s text that is showing in following screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

**Here's Layout File code:**

```
<com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/expandableButton1"
    android:background="@drawable/patient"
    android:padding="16dp"

    app:ael_duration="400"
    app:ael_expanded="true"
    app:ael_interpolator="bounce"
    app:ael_orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="340dp">
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:shrinkColumns="*" android:stretchColumns="*" android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Name:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/pname" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp" />
        <TextView />
    </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Gender:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pgender"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="DOB:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/pdob" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
        <TextView />
    </TableRow>

        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="MRN:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pmrn" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Active:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pactive" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Phone:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pphone" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Email:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pemail" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Disease:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pdisease" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Height:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pheight" android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Address:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/paddress" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
             </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Marital Status:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pmaritalstatus" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Multiple Birth:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pmultibirth" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Communication Language:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pcommlang" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Care Provider:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pcareprovider" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Race:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/prace" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Ethnicity:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/pethnicity" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
            <TextView />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
                <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Religion:" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_margin="1dp" android:gravity="start|center"/>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/preligion" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:textColor="#606062" android:gravity="left" android:layout_margin="1dp"/>
                <TextView />
            </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Add layout_margin_left equals to padding of parent.

Comment: already done that but no changes.!

Comment: still not working dude!

Comment: remove padding and put layout_margin at same rate

Comment: @VishalThakkar check my answer below and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Your xml cant be tested as whole. I tested parts of it and they seems fine. Sorry you have to figure it out yourself.

Comment: set gravity= center_horizontal

Comment: If nothing works, just add some whitespaces in the begining of text. Jugaad. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Remove the `android:padding="16dp"` from `root layout`.

```
<com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/expandableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/expandableButton1"
    app:ael_duration="400"
    app:ael_expanded="true"
    app:ael_interpolator="bounce"
    app:ael_orientation="vertical">
```

> And make changes in your `Table Layout` add `android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"`.

```
<TableLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
      android:shrinkColumns="*"
      android:stretchColumns="*">
```

Comment: Thanks it's worked but it's doesn't showing third TextView in TableRow !

Comment: @VishalThakkar do you mean `DOB text is not showing` ? It should show not an issue with that.

Comment: No, i am sorry, i am talking about third column that is blank TextView.

Comment: @VishalThakkar for that you have to write `Text` and add `TextView` property first to show the `Third Column TextView`.

Comment: @VishalThakkar Yes for that you need to add `Text` to that `Text View` then it will show you.

Comment: @VishalThakkar Accept the answer if it helped you thanks :).

Comment: Thanks @jaydroider

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all scenarios, but still TextView not shows properly, add space to String in beginning of text.

```
<string name="name">&#x20;Name</string>
```

where `&#x20;` is space.

Or if you fetch string from an API:

```
String name = " " + jsonName;
```